# oracle forms 10g multiple records data block showing records on demand

Tags: oracleforms, oracle-apps

I want to create a sale order form. For which the form should allow insertion of line items. I dont want to restrict the number of line items. I decided to display 4 empty records in which user is allowed to type line items. If he wants to type the 5th line item then i have to make the 5th empty row visible to the user. using a scroll bar he should be able to see the first record also.

How to do this in oracle forms 10g.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the *Number of Records Displayed* property of the line item block to 4 and the *Show Scrollbar* property to Yes.

Answer (score 0):

add text item based on your table (in the proprety 
database-yes ,and write ehich table the item base)
on the property of the block do the scrollbar property to yes.
add simple button to the forms and wrie commit_form.
try it